# Improving performance of SQL query for time series data

Tags: mysql, indexing, time-series, query-optimization

I'm writing a query in MySQL for a Grafana dashboard, but the performance of only this particular query is very poor.
This is the query:

```
SELECT 
        br.reading
        ,CONCAT(ino.project,"_",SUBSTRING_INDEX(br.sensor,"_",-1)) AS new_metric
        ,ino.vessel
        ,ADDTIME(DATE('2023-01-01'),-TIMEDIFF(ino.date,br.datetime)) AS norm_date        
        ,br.sensor

FROM db.milestones br
 
INNER JOIN db.projectdb ino
        ON br.datetime BETWEEN ino.date AND ino.enddate

WHERE project IN ( 'project1','project2','project3','project4' ) 
AND br.sensor LIKE CONCAT(ino.vessel , '%')
```

`EXPLAIN` output:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows     | filtered | Extra                                          |
| -- | ----------- | ----- | ---------- | ---- | ------------- | --- | ------- | --- | -------- | -------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | ino   |            | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 5        | 100.00   |                                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | br    |            | ALL  | idx_datetime  |     |         |     | 31865381 | 1.23     | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2) |
```

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `projectdb` (
   `project` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `enddate` datetime DEFAULT ((`date` + interval 3 day)),
   `vessel` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY `project_UNIQUE` (`project`),
   KEY `idx_batch` (`project`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


CREATE TABLE `milestones` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `datetime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `sensor` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `reading` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `monitor` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx_datetime` (`datetime` DESC) USING BTREE,
   KEY `idx_sensors` (`sensor`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31649068 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

indexes:

```
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
| ---------- | ---------- | -------------- | ------------ | ----------- | --------- | ----------- | -------- | ------ | ---- | ---------- | ------- | ------------- | ------- | ---------- |
| projectdb  | 0          | project_UNIQUE | 1            | project     | A         | 4           |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     |            |
| projectdb  | 1          | idx_project    | 1            | project     | A         | 5           |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     |            |
| milestones | 0          | PRIMARY        | 1            | id          | A         | 31648118    |          |        |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     |            |
| milestones | 1          | idx_datetime   | 1            | datetime    | D         | 1723411     |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     |            |
| milestones | 1          | idx_sensors    | 1            | sensor      | A         | 21924       |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     |            |
```

projectdb table sample:

```
| project   | date             | enddate          | vessel |
| --------- | ---------------- | ---------------- | ------ |
| Project 1 | 24/11/2023 17:30 | 27/11/2023 17:30 | V1     |
| Project 2 | 17/11/2023 19:50 | 20/11/2023 19:50 | V1     |
| Project 3 | 27/10/2023 16:00 | 30/10/2023 16:00 | V2     |
```

milestones table sample

```
| id       | datetime         | sensor   | reading |
| -------- | ---------------- | -------- | ------- |
| 22117821 | 10/10/2023 19:20 | V1_FT001 | 100     |
| 22118005 | 10/10/2023 19:21 | V2_FT001 | 120     |
| 22118189 | 10/10/2023 19:23 | V1_FT001 | 100     |
| 22117835 | 10/10/2023 19:20 | V3_FT001 | 105     |
```

Looking at the execution plan, it's evident that the index on `db.milestones.sensor` and `db.milestones.datetime` are not being used. This means that the full table scan needs to go through all 36 million rows, which explains the poor performance. I'm assuming because this is time series data, I have 81 sensors repeating over and over, making the index less likely to be used.

Is there a way to modify this query to make it so the index is always used, or is it a matter of taking an entirely different approach if I want to improve query speeds?

I tried using a subquery in the first join to include the `WHERE` clause at the end to filter out unnecessary data before joining. This approach ended up being the worst performing taking up to 2 minutes.

I tried to create a view of the db.milestones table to contain the substring which the `WHERE` clause is being compared against, so I could use `=` instead of `LIKE`. This also did not go as expected, the performance was very bad as well.

I tried to use `FORCE INDEX` to use the index but this didn't work.

Interestingly, if I reduce the conditions in `WHERE project IN...` , the index on `db.milestone.sensor`is used and the processing time is much better.

Comment: I think this question (being about query optimization) is better suited for [dba.se].

Comment: The first step issue that I see is with your JOIN conditions. You've mentioned a JOIN but haven't specified the type (INNER, LEFT, etc.) and the ON clause is missing in your provided query. Ensure that your JOIN conditions are correctly defined.

Comment: The subquery JOIN with min table doesn´t make sense because you are not using it. Also the ON clause for your first JOIN is missing

Comment: Apologies for the type on the first JOIN, it is indeed missing the ON but this wasn't the issue with performance. As nacho pointed out it does seem like the subquery JOIN was pointless as well. 

As for the type of JOIN it seems as though this doesn't effect query speeds either.

Comment: One more thing: your problem doesn't seems to be in any way related to Grafana. If you'll invoke same query manually substituting `${project:sqlstring}` with some list of projects, you'll have same issue with performance. If this is the case - consider removing mentions of Grafana to ease understanding of question and minimize scope of possible problem.

Comment: Please add the full DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;`) for the two tables and the output of `EXPLAIN` for your current query. A few rows of sample data so we can understand the relationship between `br.sensor LIKE CONCAT(ino.vessel , '%')` would be helpful. Also, some index stats (`SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name;`).To get a significant improvement in performance you need a composite index on `milestones (sensor, datetime)` but your current data structure/query would not be able to use it as both the join conditions require range scans.

Comment: Please please study up on `JOIN ... ON`.  If the `ON` clause fails to specify something that relates the first table to the second one, the query generates a combinatorial explosion of all possible combinations of rows in the two tables. And, yeah, those combinatorial explosions are often vary slow. The `WHERE` clause can contain these relational items too. But I don't see them in your query. Without them it's hard to see what you're trying to do with the query.

Comment: *I tried to use FORCE INDEX to use the index but this didn't work.* Didn't work means: index is not used nevertheless, the performance is degraded, something else...

Comment: @user1191247 I have updated the original post to include more detail.

Comment: `reading` and `idbioreactors` are missing.

Comment: The post is updated to sort out this issue @RickJames

Comment: (`INNER` and `OUTER` qualifiers on `JOIN` are ignored by MySQL.)

Comment: I suspect that the expression for `norm_date` is wrong.  `TIMEDIFF returns a "time", not a date+time; I'm not sure negating works, etc.

Comment: Is `projects` a typo for `projectdb`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have two indices on the `project` column, one of which is unique, and there is no PK. You should drop the two existing indices and add PK on `project`.

The key to reasonable performance is the composite key on `(sensor, datetime)` and a concrete relationship between `vessel` and `sensor`.

Adding a simple join table (`vessel_sensor`) would make the world of difference:

| vessel | sensor |
| --- | --- |
| V1 | V1_FT001 |
| V2 | V2_FT001 |
| V3 | V3_FT001 |

And the composite index:

```sql
ALTER TABLE milestones ADD INDEX idx_sensor_datetime (sensor, datetime);
```

Then add the join table to your existing query:

```sql
SELECT 
    m.reading,
    CONCAT(p.project, '_', SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.sensor, '_', -1)) AS new_metric,
    p.vessel,
    ADDTIME(DATE('2023-01-01'), -TIMEDIFF(p.date, m.datetime)) AS norm_date,
    m.sensor
FROM projects p
JOIN vessel_sensor vs
    ON vs.vessel = p.vessel
JOIN milestones m
    ON m.sensor = vs.sensor
    AND m.datetime BETWEEN p.date AND p.enddate
WHERE p.project IN ( 'project1', 'project2', 'project3', 'project4' );
```

Comment: Note that `project` must be `NOT NULL` for it to be the PK.

Answer (score 0):

*(rewritten Answer based on revised schemas:)*

For `milestones`, change from

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `idx_datetime` (`datetime` DESC) USING BTREE,
 KEY `idx_sensors` (`sensor`) USING BTREE
```

to

```
 PRIMARY KEY(sensor, datetime, id),
 INDEX(id),
 INDEX(datetime)
```

and...

```
CREATE TABLE `projectdb` (
   `project` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   -- Note "NOT"
   `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `enddate` datetime DEFAULT ((`date` + interval 3 day)),
   `vessel` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`project`),          -- Note
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: @Issie - I rewrote my Answer.